# AssertionError: wrong color format 'ansibrightred'

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I am running my old `qiskit` code after a very long time it's not running now showing error `wrong color format 'ansibrightred'` and I don't know why?

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister
# %matplotlib inline

circuit = QuantumCircuit(3,3)
circuit.h(0)
circuit.h(1)
circuit.h(2)
circuit.measure([0,1], [0,1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. I solved it by removing my install and installing qiskit==0.16.2.

```
pip install qiskit==0.16.2
```